# How to update a observable in serviceA everytime when function B in service B is updated?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I know i should use Observable for creating this behaviour. But not sure exactly how to do.

**serviceA.service.ts**

```
private tobeUpdated: Observable<any>;

constructor( private serviceB: serviceB){}

// Whenever any change happens in function B of serviceB, call this function

this.tobeUpdated = this.serviceB.B();
this.tobeUpdated.subscribe((data) => {
     //do my operations
})
```

**serviceB.service.ts**

```
    private message:[];

   B(){
        message.push("I updated this variable");
      // Now i need to pass this message to service A
      return message;
   }
```

Now how to update the **"tobeUpdated"** variable in serviceA, whenever function B is updated in service B.

I should update everytime function B is invoked.

I'm new to angular and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your B() should return instance of Observable, so you can call emit() and then subscribe() to emitted events elsewhere

Comment: you can use subject for that and you can pass a new value with .next(your new value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subjects for that.

**Subject** if you don't want to hold the first value,
**BehaviorSubject** if you need the first value.

#### Service B

```js
// Either of them but not both, duh
toUpdate: Subject<any> = new Subject();
toUpdate: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

B() {
  this.toUpdate.next('Your message or your array of messages');
}
```

#### Service A

```js
constructor(B: serviceB) {
  B.toUpdate.subscribe(message => {
    // Your operations
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by:

1. Importing serviceA inside serviceB.
2. In ServiceA, make the toBeUpdated variable public or have a set() method that can be called by serviceB.
3. In the constructor of serviceB create/inject  serviceA.
4. Using the object obtained in step 2, call the appropriate method (toBeUpdated of serviceA).

I can’t see your actual class names but step 3 and 4 can be as follows.  This is assuming that toBeUpdated isn’t private

```
constructor(private objserviceA :   
ServiceA) { }
 // step 4 below
 this.objserviceA.toBeUpdated =xyz
```

In this tutorial, they inject MessageService into HeroService.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1):

You should use Subject and subscribe to it. Remember also to unsubscribe.

This could be an example

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

export class ClassA {
  private tobeUpdated: Observable<string>;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor( private serviceB: ServiceB){
    this.tobeUpdated = this.serviceB.B();
    this.subscription = this.tobeUpdated.subscribe(data => {
       //do my operations
       console.log('the messagge received is ', data);
    })
  }

  stop() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

class ServiceB {
  private message$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  emitMessagge(message: string) {
    this.message$.next(message);
  }

  B() {
    return this.message$.asObservable();
  }

}

const B = new ServiceB();
const A = new ClassA(B);

B.emitMessagge('first');
B.emitMessagge('second');
B.emitMessagge('third');

A.stop();
```

Comment: It was helpful !Thanks a lot!!